# Setting time in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I would like to implement an `EditText` that operates similarly to the android alarm app. In this app, there are two `EditText` fields that serve as the `HH` and `mm`. Typing in these fields overwrites the number that was previously there. When you have typed the second number into the `HH` field, focus automatically switches to the `mm` field.

I have tried to put this logic in manually using a `TextWatcher` in the `afterTextChanged()` method, but unfortunately modifying the text whilst in this method causes a recursive loop.

What's the correct way to implement this?

See below for alarm app example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out editing the text from the `onTextChanged` method doesn't actually cause a recursive loop, as long as you temporarily disable the logic with a boolean switch. Painstakingly wrote in all the logic into the `TextWatcher` to mimic the alarm-style `EditText` fields.

Answer (score 0):

add listener to your hh text view like this

```
 hh.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (hh.getText().toString().length() == 2){
                mm.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

hope this will work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately `android:maxLength="2"` does not work in this scenario. The `EditText` will always have 2 digits in it (from the start) - so when the user tries to type, it has to over-write what is already there. By setting the `maxLength` to 2, it effectively blocks the `TextChangedListener` from ever capturing a 'new digit' that is input by the user - because as soon as the user inputs a new digit - it is ignored due to the `EditText` having reached it's maximum.

Comment: Please have a look at the alarm app on an android phone to see what I mean - you'll get a better idea of the behaviour I'm trying to replicate.